# Sonarqube exclude code coverage for tests but include in code smell and duplicate detection

Tags: c#, sonarqube

If I specify `<SonarQubeTestProject>true</SonarQubeTestProject>` it will exclude the project from not just code coverage but also code smell and duplicate detection.

Is there a way to just exclude from code coverage but scan for every other aspects?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [Exclusions](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/project-administration/narrowing-the-focus/), which allow you to exclude files from

- consideration altogether
- issues
- coverage
- duplications

Comment: Do you mind sharing what you think about what I requested for? If it makes sense to you or the SonarQube team, any reason for SonarQube to default to not scanning code smell and duplicates for Test assemblies? Specifically C#, if it matters.

Comment: SonarC# actually analyzes the test code, the result is not uploaded to SonarQube for various reasons. We will be changing that in the very near future, you could see the following tickets for some of the required steps: https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-csharp/issues/861 https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-csharp/issues/1087 https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARMSBRU-345

Comment: Above Exclusions link is changed, so I am proving new link of Exclusions https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/project-administration/narrowing-the-focus/